# Generate table with rowspan using Angular 2

Tags: angular, grid-layout

I have a data structure like this:

```
    [
  "category1": {
    "name": "Cat 1",
    "competences": [{
      "name": "Comp 1",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Comp 2",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    }]
  },
  "category2": {
    "name": "Cat 2",
    "competences": [{
      "name": "Comp 3",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Comp 4",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    },… {
      "name": "Comp N",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    }]
  },
  "categoryN": {
    "name": "Cat N",
    "competences": [{
      "name": "Comp 5",
      "users": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "level": 99,
      }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "level": 99,
      },… {
        "name": "userN",
        "level": 9001,
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

Basically a list of categories, with all competences within that category, and for each competence type, a record for every user (so the number of users will be equal for each competence).

Now I want to generate a table from this:

```
+----------------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|                | user 1 | user 2 | … | user N |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
| Cat 1 | Comp 1 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
|       +--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|       | Comp 2 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
| Cat 2 | Comp 3 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
|       +--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|       | Comp 4 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
|       +--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|       | …      | …      | …      | … | …      |
+       +--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|       | Comp N | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
| Cat 3 | Comp 5 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
|       +--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
|       | Comp 6 | 99     | 99     | … | 9001   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+---+--------+
```

Which means `rowspan` will be involved. However, I can’t get a grip on how to start.

If I write

```
<tr *ngFor="let category for categories">
    <td [rowspan]="category.components.length">
```

I get

```
Can't bind to 'rowspan' since it isn't a known native property
```

So my question is: how to bind a template value to the rowspan property?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Rowspan itself is no native property, it's an attribute. So what you have to do is to access the element's rowspan attribute as follows:

```
<td [attr.rowspan]="category.components.length"></td>
```

That should do the trick and you are now setting the value for `rowspan`. You **must** use attribute binding when there is no element property to bind to. If you want to read more on that, check out the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it indeed helped (even though the project took an unexpected turn since then, and we won’t use this approach at all)

Comment: some updated documentation https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding